# postgres upsert returning even if not inserting

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I've read [the insert doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html).  I'm not sure I follow every line, but I've read it.

I have a table that's a mapping from query strings to uuids:

```
create table foo.query_uuids (
    query_string    text not null primary key,
    uuid            uuid not null unique)
```

when I get a query string, I want to get the pre-existing uuid if I have one, and create one if not.

## things that don't work

My first thought was this:

```
insert into foo.query_uuids (query_string, uuid) values (?, uuid(?))
    on conflict on constraint query_uuids_pkey do nothing
    returning uuid::text
```

but that only returns if the row is created/changed.  I *could* do a thing where I make a second query if I get nothing back, because lack of response means that there's something there.  But that's roughly doubling the round trips to the db.

Then I tried updating the "excluded" row.

```
insert into foo.query_uuids (query_string, uuid) values (?, uuid(?))
    on conflict on constraint query_uuids_pkey do update set excluded.uuid = uuid
    returning uuid::text
```

That doesn't work either, giving me `ERROR: column "excluded" of relation "query_uuids" does not exist` which does actually make sense.

## current best solution

I have this, which works, but is technically updating the row all the time.  [This guy](http://fmcgeough.github.io/postgres-upsert/) appears to have come across the same idea.  It does work, but I think it means that I can't have triggers and such.  And it just makes the functional programmer in me start whining about immutable data...

```
insert into foo.query_uuids (query_string, uuid) values (?, uuid(?)) 
    on conflict on constraint query_uuids_pkey do update set query_string = excluded.query_string 
    returning uuid::text
```

Is there a way to ***not*** update the row, but have a single round trip that doesn't suffer from race conditions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I’m smelling a data-modifying CTE here. And what race condition are you worried about?